# Doesn't work "onchange" in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, onchange, input-type-file

I have some issues with the `onchange` attribute in IE 7-9. It doesn't work with `input type="file"` tag. In other browsers, it works good.

This is my code:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
            <input type="file" name="photo" class="File" onchange="$('form').submit();"/></br>
            <input type="button" class="BigButton" onClick="$('.File').click();"/>
 </form>
```

This is my CSS style for the input file

```
input.File {
position: relative;
text-align: right;
-moz-opacity:0 ;
filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Your English is good enough. Could you add your code here so that we can see how you are setting the onchange event for the input tag? Be sure to format the code properly (click on the curly brackets in the toolbar).

Comment: good job. Now let's see if you get an answer.

Comment: @DOK, I forget add a css code.See it again, please

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me. Are you sure you are using `onchange` this way?

```
<input type="file" onchange="alert('')" />
```

Comment: In IE9 doesn't work.All other versions i tested by changing browser mode.

Comment: I can't test in IE9. Maybe you need a Doctype?

Comment: Main page have xhtml doctype, but loaded in iframe page with mycode doesn't have.

Comment: Then try with a Doctype on the page in the iFrame.